# Не работает сайт на DJango

Tags: python, django

Делаю сайт на Django. На локальном сервере, где его делаю, всё работает хорошо, но при попытке переноса его на хостинг Reg.ru он не запускается и выходят какие-то ошибки. Как я понял, ошибки не критические, а вот в самом низу, ругается, что нет модуля accounts.

UPD  Еще заметил, что VSC подчеркивает на models, filters & filtras

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
App 18590 output: /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py:26: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
App 18590 output:   import sys, os, re, imp, threading, signal, traceback, socket, select, struct, logging, errno
App 18590 output: Traceback (most recent call last):
App 18590 output:   File "/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 369, in <module>
App 18590 output:     app_module = load_app()
App 18590 output: 
App 18590 output:   File "/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/wsgi-loader.py", line 76, in load_app
App 18590 output:     return imp.load_source('passenger_wsgi', startup_file)
App 18590 output: 
App 18590 output:   File "/opt/python/python-3.9.0/lib/python3.9/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
App 18590 output:     module = _load(spec)
App 18590 output: 
App 18590 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 711, in _load
App 18590 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
App 18590 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
App 18590 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
App 18590 output:   File "/var/www/u1245015/data/www/omegasnabkomplekt.ru/passenger_wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
App 18590 output:     application = get_wsgi_application()
App 18590 output: 
App 18590 output:   File "/var/www/u1245015/data/www/omegasnabkomplekt.ru/omegaenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
App 18590 output:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
App 18590 output: 
App 18590 output:   File "/var/www/u1245015/data/www/omegasnabkomplekt.ru/omegaenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
App 18590 output:     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
App 18590 output: 
App 18590 output:   File "/var/www/u1245015/data/www/omegasnabkomplekt.ru/omegaenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
App 18590 output:     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
App 18590 output: 
App 18590 output:   File "/var/www/u1245015/data/www/omegasnabkomplekt.ru/omegaenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 224, in create
App 18590 output:     import_module(entry)
App 18590 output: 
App 18590 output:   File "/opt/python/python-3.9.0/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
App 18590 output:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
App 18590 output: 
App 18590 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
App 18590 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
App 18590 output:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
App 18590 output: ModuleNotFoundError
App 18590 output: : No module named 'accounts'
```

**SETTINGS.PY**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-bt0p_acxm-!0krg+hktb6hrzh(nx_'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['osk.ru', 'www.osk.ru']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'accounts',
    'import_export',
    'guest',
    'lootbag',
    'django_filters',
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'omega.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'omega.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATIC_ROOT='static/',

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
 




# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

**URLS.PY**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('accounts.urls'))
]
```

ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ  accounts

**ADMIN.PY**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from import_export import resources

# Register your models here.

from models import *
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
from .models import *
from guest.models import *
from .views import *

from .filters import *
from .filtars import *

# from django.core.paginator import Paginator


def glavnaya(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/glavnaya.html')

def spetsstali(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/spetsstali.html')






def alyuminievyj_prokat(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/alyuminievyj-prokat.html')

def tsvetnoj_prokat_i_splavy(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/tsvetnoj-prokat-i-splavy.html')
```

**URLS.PY**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.conf import include
from . import views




urlpatterns = [
   
   # path('snippets/', include('lootbag.urls', namespace='snippets')),

    path('', views.tsvetnoj_prokat_i_splavy),
   #  path('products/', views.products),
   #  path('customer/', views.customer),
    path('glavnaya/', views.glavnaya),
    path('tsvetnoj-prokat-i-splavy/', views.tsvetnoj_prokat_i_splavy),



    path('tsvetnoj-prokat-i-splavy/alyuminievyj-prokat/', views.alyuminievyj_prokat),
```

Comment: ну и что это за accounts ? какая-то библиотека? или ваше приложение?

Comment: Здравствуйте. Это просто название приложения. 
Первый раз задаю тут вопрос и не особо понимаю, что и как тут показывать)
Что конкретно мне надо показать?

Comment: если это название вашего приложения покажите настройки settings.py

Comment: Добавил содержимое settings